# Kubernetes service created via exposed deployment is not responding to curl

Tags: kubernetes

I deployed my application using deployment construct. State of my pod is `Running` and making **curl** against pod's IP returns application content. However when I created service using `kubectl expose deployment` and I **curl** service's IP then curl throws `Connection refused` error. Why is that?

### My pod

```
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP          NODE        NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
cge-frontend-5d4595469b-qvcsd   0/1     Running   0          19s   10.40.0.4   compute04   <none>           <none>
```

### My service

```
NAME           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
cge-frontend   ClusterIP   10.98.212.184   <none>        80/TCP    16m
```

### Error

```
$ curl 10.98.212.184
curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.98.212.184:80; Connection refused
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigating my service with `kubectl describe svc` command. I fogure out that my service has no `Endpoints` - endpoints section should list pod's IP.

```
$ kubectl describe svc cge-frontend 
Name:              cge-frontend
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=cge-frontend
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=cge-frontend
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.98.212.184
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         
Session Affinity:  None
```

It turned out that, the error was caused by one of my `probe` that was keeping my pod in `Running` state but not in `Ready`state. Fixing probes, fixed my pods, and that fixed the service.

My pod after fixing probes is now in correct state `READY 1/1`

```
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP          NODE        NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
cge-frontend-5d4595469b-qvcsd   1/1     Running   0          19s   10.40.0.5   compute04   <none>           <none>
```